# Bash script how to accept single or double digit number and make it 2 digit

Tags: bash, printf, floating-point

I have a following simple extract from my script which is strangely stuck up for a particular inputs.

```
echo -e "Enter the Day of the Month : \c "
    read input_day
    printf -v input_day '%02d' "$input_day"
```

This makes sure that if the user inputs a single digit number e.g. 2 then it converts it to 02. Which is my first requirement. This also works if one enters 2 digits number as 02. Then it retains it as 02.
This also works for a 2 digit number as 12.
But strangely it fails to accept the digit 08 and 09? 
This is the error it gives when one enters 08 or 09.

```
Enter the Day of the Month : 08
2: line 20: printf: 08: invalid number
```

Why is it so? I tried to read printf help page and it shows that "d" stands for Signed decimal integer. So it should accept the digits 8 and 9. Or am I missing something? My requirement is that user should be able to enter the day of the month as single digit "8" as well as double digit "08".

Comment: a number which starts with '0' is an octal number. Octal digits can reach from 0 to 7. Therefore 08 and 09 are invalid numbers

Comment: You can force conversion to different base. Use the following
`$(( 10#$input_day ))`
to convert your input to base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` will interpret a number with a leading zero as octal.  The format is not the problem, the `$input_day` variable is the problem.

You can remove those with a variety of methods (see for example *[awk equivalent of LTRIM function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819687/awk-equivalent-of-ltrim-function-in-c/35826594#35826594)*).

Further reading:

- [Removing leading zeros before passing the variable to iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123717/removing-leading-zeros-before-passing-the-variable-to-iptables)
  uses this syntax: `$((10#$machinenumber))`, e.g., for your example:

  ```
  printf -v input_day '%02d' "$((10#$input_day))"
  ```
- [Bash: Removing leading zeroes from a variable](https://coderwall.com/p/cobcna/bash-removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-variable)
  is more to the point:

  `shopt -s extglob
  printf -v input_day '%02d' ${input_day##+(0)}`

By the way, the example does not check if the variable is empty.  But validating that properly would be another question.

Comment: I referred to the post you suggested. But could not figure out how to implement here. You mean to replace $input_day with awk ??

Comment: Hello, printf -v input_day '%02d' "$((10#$input_day))" works neat!!!